# Translation Golf XI - The Doom that Came to Sarnath

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

[H.P. Lovecraft](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft) es un autor estadounidense de novelas fantásticas y relatos de terror, entre los que destacan sus *Mitos de Cthulu*.

Para el *translation golf* de esta semana he elegido un texto descriptivo de "[The Doom that Came to Sarnath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doom_that_Came_to_Sarnath)", una obra a caballo entre su "ciclo del Sueño" y "Los Mitos de Cthulu".

> It is written on the brick cylinders of Kadatheron that the beings of Ib were in hue as green as the lake and the mists that rise above it; that they had bulging eyes, pouting, flabby lips, and curious ears, and were without voice. However this may be, it is certain that they worshipped a sea-green stone idol chiselled in the likeness of Bokrug, the great water-lizard; before which they danced horribly when the moon was gibbous.

Una posible (**377 caracteres**) traducción sería:

> En los cilindros de arcilla de Kadatheron está escrito que los habitantes de Ib eran, por su color, tan verdes como el lago y las nieblas que de él se elevan; que poseían abultados ojos y labios gruesos y blandos y extrañas orejas y que carecían de voz. Cierto es, en todo caso, que adoraban un ídolo, tallado en piedra verdemar, que representaba a Bokrug, el gran saurio acuático, ante el cual celebraban danzas horribles cuando la luna gibosa mostraba su doble cuerno.

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: La siguiente pregunta para el foro: ¿Cómo se pronuncia "Cthulu"? :-D

Comment: En ese caso puedes llamarme blando. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### <strike>281</strike> <strike>271</strike> <strike>257</strike> 240 caracteres

> Según los rollos de arcilla de Kadatheron, los seres de Ib eran verdosos como el lago y la bruma dél; ojos saltones, labios tristes y flojos, orejas atentas, mudos. Como sea, de seguro adoraban una imagen de piedra verdemar de Bokrug, el gran reptil marino; ante él danzaban feamente so la luna gibosa.

Versión 0:

- Había puesto "**laguarto**" como palabro para "lagarto de agua" la primera vez que le di a enviar, pero acabo de ver que no se registró. Se ve que las ediciones en el primer minuto no se guardan :( Una pena, porque la palabra me parecía graciosa...

Versión 1:

- [Rollo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=WdApXKx): Cilindro de madera, metal u otra materia, generalmente dura.
- **Triste**: *pouting* quiere decir "haciendo pucheros". Lo mejor que se me ha ocurrido para expresar esto es que los labios parecían tristes.
- [De seguro](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=seguro): ciertamente, en verdad.
- Omisión de "esculpido": creo que diciendo "ídolo de piedra a imagen de" se sobreentiende el "esculpido".
- [Verdemar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=verdemar): el color verde del mar.
- [Feamente](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=feamente): por horriblemente, siendo [horrible](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=horrible) sinónimo de (muy) feo.
- [Gibosa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fase_lunar#Descripci.C3.B3n_de_las_fases): no es solo [un adjetivo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=gibosa), es que es el nombre de esa fase de la luna.

Versión 2:

- «***Dicen***» en vez de «*Está escrito en*». Igual que en «El libro dice que...».
- «***Sobre este***» en vez de «*que sobre él flota*». Se entiende que la bruma, si está sobre algo, es flotando, no sentada :P

Versión 3

- "*la bruma sobre este*" por "***la bruma [dél](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=d%C3%A9l)***";
- "*Dicen los rollos que (...)*" por "***Según los rollos,** (...)*";
- "*un ídolo a imagen de*" por, directamente, "***una [imagen](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=imagen) de***" (segunda acepción);
- "*bajo*" por "***[so](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Y3Da92X)***".

Comment: Tengo la duda acerca de si _"curious ears"_ significa "oídos atentos" u "orejas de forma rara"; la alusión anterior a la forma de los labios me hace pensar lo segundo, pero la mención posterior de que no hablaban, lo primero. Aunque, si fuera la forma, sería más lógico que el original dijera _"curiously-shaped ears"_ o algo así.

Comment: Creo que "atentos" es lo más acertado. Lovecraft era de usar arcaísmos y giros ingleses, igual, y tal vez sea ambiguo adrede. _"Brick cylinders"_ es raro, porque no encuentro _"brick"_ como sinónimo de "arcilla", y _"cylinder"_ por "torre" es extraño también, a menos que se refiera a estructuras cilíndricas que no se sepa qué son.

Comment: El original dice que son "cilindros hechos de ladrillo"; _"brick"_ no figura en los diccionarios que miré como sinónimo de"arcilla" (puede ser una licencia, igual). Yo interpreto que se refiere a alguna estructura cilíndrica hecha de ladrillos, como una torre (o una estructura con un fin desconocido, por eso se limita a llamarla "cilindro"). Un cilindro de arcilla me recuerda a los sellos cilíndricos babilonios, por ejemplo, ideales como soporte de una inscripción, pero no estrictamente hechos de ladrillo; aunque insisto en que no llego a interpretar la intención del autor, por ahora.

Comment: Leyendo el original, llego a la conclusión de que son cilindros de ladrillo hechos como soporte de una inscripción: los "cilindros de ladrillo de Kadatheron" serían como, por caso, "los rollos del Mar Muerto", o sea, nada de torres. Quedaría ver si es aceptable"arcilla" por "ladrillo".

Comment: @walen yo, yoyoyoyo, yoyo, yoyoyoyo, yo quiero el cuchillooooooo... qué mítica escena... sabía que la iba a ver incluso antes de pulsar tu enlace. :-D

Comment: Yo interpreto, sin darle muchas vueltas, que podrían ser cilindros (del tamaño que tendrían los cartuchos para papiros) hechos de arcilla cocida o similar. Este cartucho lo pasaría (rodarías) por otra superficie (una tableta de arcilla blanda, por ejemplo) para dejar impreso el mensaje contenido en el cilindro. Vamos, una forma muy rudimentaria de "imprenta". Pero estoy divagando. "Arcilla" se acepta para esa traducción.

Comment: @Diego Sí, esos son, precisamente, los sellos cilíndricos babilonios que había mencionado en otro comentario. Me parecen un poco pequeños como para que se los describa como "hechos de ladrillo", pero no disponemos de mayores precisiones.

Comment: ¡Gran idea la de reducir texto usando "imagen de piedra"!

Comment: Enhorabuena Walen, eres el ganador de esta edición!

Answer (score 4):

### 277 caracteres

> Pone en los cilindros de ladrillo de Kadatheron que los seres de Ib eran verdes como el lago y la niebla sobre él, de ojos saltones, labios flácidos y salientes, oído atento, y mudos; como fuere, vero es que adoraban un pétreo ídolo verdemar tallado a imagen de Bokrug, el gran reptil acuático, y ante él danzaban fieramente con la luna casi llena.

[Miasma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PAG6Ifx): Efluvio maligno que, según se creía, desprendían cuerpos enfermos, materias corruptas o aguas estancadas.

[Fiero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HsDQ07D): 6. adj. Horroroso, terrible.

- Editado porque olvidé la parte de las orejas.
- Cambio "verde agua" por "verdemar", y pongo "pétreo" por delante, que suena mejor pero no modifica la cuenta de caracteres.
- Cambio "miasma" por "niebla"; en efecto, si bien sería muy propio de Lovecraft que esa niebla fuese maligna, no lo ha indicado explícitamente.
- Cambio "orejas curiosas" por "oído atento".

Answer (score 3):

### <strike>295</strike> 254 caracteres

> Se talló en los rulos de argila de Kadatheron que los seres de Ib eran verdes como el lago y su bruma; de ojos saltones, labios cansados y flojos, oídos atentos y sin voz. Como fuere, se sabe que oraban a un ídolo de piedra verdemar con forma de Bokrug, el gran reptil de agua: danzábanle macabros llegando el plenilunio.

- [Argila](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3XKq7o2) (forma en desuso de "arcilla").
- Uso "el lago y sus nieblas" para denotar "las nieblas sobre el lago".
- [Orar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R8h4PV7) ("dirigirse mentalmente o de palabra a una divinidad o a una persona sagrada, frecuentemente para hacerles una súplica", por idolatrar).
- [Verdemar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bcAVplw) (de un color verde similar al del mar).
- [Semeja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XVswnf1) (en desuso: "semejanza").

Sobre lo de que la luna estaba "gibbous", según el Merriam-Webster [significa](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gibbous) "que se ve más de la mitad de su disco aparente, pero no todo". De ahí traducirlo como "cuando se acercaba la luna llena" y no como propone Diego.

Actualización 1:

- Cambio *rodillos* por *[rulos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WpBiYpg)* (rodillo para allanar el suelo).
- Cambio *escribir* por *[tallar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z0NDGtY)* (elaborar muy cuidadosamente una obra).
- Cambio *niebla* por *[bruma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6BB5hPp)*.
- Cambio *orejas* por *oídos*.
- Cambio *tallado a semeja de* por *con forma de*.
- Reescrita la última frase.

Comment: Genial muestra de pensamiento lateral con lo de las fases de la luna.